# .htaccess and PHP files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have written a .htaccess file to address certain security issues with a site I have been working on.

Things such as:

- HSTS
- Frame options
- Sniffing options
- CSP

The issue I have is that the file seems to work with the following:

- HTML
- CSS
- JS
- PDF

But does not work on PHP files.

When working with PHP files do you need to explicitly use `header()`?

Just in case I'm being dense I've included the file.

```
#############################
## ERROR MESSAGES REDIRECT ##
#############################
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
#############################
## ERROR MESSAGES REDIRECT ##
#############################


############################
# DISABLE SERVER SIGNATURE #
############################
ServerSignature Off
############################
# DISABLE SERVER SIGNATURE #
############################


#################
## VARY HEADER ##
#################
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

  Header always add TestHeader "It works."

  ######################################
  ## Set X headers for extra security ##
  ######################################
  # 1. HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) header
  # 2. CSP - Only allow content from particular places
  # 3. XXS Protection - Protect from XXS
  # 4. X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN - Only allow frames within this domain
  # 5. X-Content-Type-Options nosniff - Disable browser sniffing
  Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=631138519; includeSubDomains"
  Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com
  Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
  Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
  Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
  ######################################
  ## Set X headers for extra security ##
  ######################################


  ##################### 
  ## Unset X headers ##
  ##################### 
  Header unset X-Powered-By
  ##################### 
  ## Unset X headers ##
  #####################


  ##################### 
  ## Vary headers ##
  ##################### 
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz|html|php|woff|woff2)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
  ##################### 
  ## Vary headers ##
  #####################   


#####################
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
#####################
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault                                   "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css                            "access plus 1 year"
# Data interchange
ExpiresByType application/json                    "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml                     "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/xml                            "access plus 0 seconds"
# Favicon (cannot be renamed!)
ExpiresByType image/x-icon                        "access plus 1 week"
# HTML components (HTCs)
ExpiresByType text/x-component                    "access plus 1 month"
# HTML
ExpiresByType text/html                           "access plus 0 seconds"
# JavaScript
ExpiresByType application/javascript              "access plus 1 year"
# Manifest files
ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                 "access plus 0 seconds"
# Media
ExpiresByType audio/ogg                           "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif                           "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg                          "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png                           "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4                           "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/ogg                           "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/webm                          "access plus 1 month"
# Web feeds
ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                 "access plus 1 hour"
# Web fonts
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2              "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject       "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf              "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype                       "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                       "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
#####################
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
#####################


#################
## COMPRESSION ##
#################
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff2
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
</IfModule>
#################
## COMPRESSION ##
#################
```

I added TestHeader as a means of checking.

To view headers I have been using https://securityheaders.io/

**The below is from a HTML file**

[image]

**The below is from a PHP file**

[image]

As you can see the additional headers are completely ignored.

Does PHP process .htaccess files differently?

I am running PHP 7.

Comment: I think you copy and pasted your .htaccess file into this question, which means it is what you have on the server. You're missing an ending double quote on the line starting with `Header set Content-Security-Policy "`

Comment: "Does PHP process .htaccess files differently?" - `.htaccess` is processed by Apache, before PHP. However, PHP can override any of these headers (although that would seem unlikely). What is the handler for PHP - are these perhaps handled by an external process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the hosting provider I'm with (1&1) restrict the headers that can be set with certain files.

**Quote from email**

"Actually we do have a restriction, as additional headers set by customer .htaccess do not work on PHP scripts (or in general on CGI scripts). If you use PHP function header(), it will work. Just .htaccess cannot do the trick for PHP scripts."

```
<?php
/*
- 1. Strict Transport Security
- 2. Content Security Policy
- 3. XSS Protection
- 4. X Frame Options
- 5. X Content Options
- 6. Referrer Policy
*/

$headerSTS = "Strict-Transport-Security:" . "max-age=631138519; includeSubDomains";
$headerCSP = "Content-Security-Policy:" . 
             "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *;" .
             "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' code.jquery.com https://cse.google.com https://www.google.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://ajax.googleapis.com https://www.gstatic.com;" .
             "img-src 'self' https://www.google.com https://www.google-analytics.com *;" .
             "media-src 'self' http://player.vimeo.com;" .
             "frame-src 'self' http://player.vimeo.com;";
$headerXSS = "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block";
$headerSO = "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN";
$headerNS = "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff";
$headerReferrer = "Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade";

header($headerSTS);
header($headerCSP);
header($headerXSS);
header($headerSO);
header($headerNS);
header($headerReferrer);
?>
```

After some reading I found that the above does the trick if your hosting provider does not allow certain changes within the `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 2):

.htaccess Files tells apache what to do, it is not processed by PHP